# Unable to get the value of the input field with *ngIf for angular 2 with material

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-material

I am trying to access the value of the input field and pass it to the method when I click on a button. The problem here is that the scope of the input field is restricted to mat-form-field in first case.  [stackblitz DEMO](https://angular-pqfaa5.stackblitz.io)

```
  <mat-form-field *ngIf="bool">
   <input matInput #input placeholder="Enter 1st input">
  </mat-form-field>
  <button click=someMethod(input?.value)>Submit</button>
```

someMethod() will have the no value

If I try to do the same thing without *ngIf then it works and I am able to access the value globally.

```
  <mat-form-field>
   <input matInput #input2 placeholder="Enter 2nd input">
  </mat-form-field>

  <button click=someMethod(input2?.value)>Submit</button>
```

in this case someMethod() will receive the value

In the demo I was able to access the value with viewChild but I want to know why I am not able to access the value if I use ngIf.
Thanks in advance.
NOTE: I am not looking for an alternative to the issue, I want to know whats wrong with the first approach.

Comment: Your implementation to retrieve the `input` value is a bit strange. The common practice in Angular would be to use [template driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms) or [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). Is there a reason you're not using either of those forms?

Comment: Hey @Narm thanks for the response and yes I am not using formControl as this form will be conditionally rendered based on the user selection so I dont want to declare the formControl and I just want to access the value on click of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read [this blog post](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/thomas/2017/05/use-angular-template-reference-variables-anywhere-in-the-template-not.html) by Thomas Hilzendegen for a good explanation of what is happening.

The scope of a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) is the template in which it is defined. In your second code sample, where no `ngIf` condition is applied, the variable `input2` is available everywhere in the template.

When an `*ngIf` directive is used however, the variable `input` is actually defined inside an inner template created by the directive. Here is the desugared markup corresponding to your first example:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="bool">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput #input placeholder="Enter 1st input">
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>
<button click=someMethod(input?.value)>Submit</button>
```

You see that the definition of the variable `input` is inside of the inner template, but the button is trying to access it outside of that template, where it is undefined.

[This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7je5mj) shows the limited scope of a variable defined in a conditional directive.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging found that a variable declared inside of an *ngIf cannot be used outside of the *ngIf as it is not supported by the design as per the discussion on https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6179#issuecomment-233579605
Alternate way of doing it would be using ViewChild or hidden or adding ngClass for conditional display none and block of the element like https://angular-pqfaa5-we74s5.stackblitz.io